# pass value from first window to second window pressing button and should hide first window after press button

Tags: c++, qt

there are two Windows in this project. the first one is naming as firstform and the other as seconform.

in the firstform the user can type on the QlineEdit and then click on the button. the firstform close and secondform will be open, and in the second window on the label, the typed one should display.

it means the data in the lineEdit in the first window should pass to the second window's label

Comment: So what did you try, to solve this? And _how_ is your attempt not working?

Comment: i was try with SLOT and SIGNAL it was work, but when i run the program both windows are showing

but i need to after the press button on the first window and open second window and show the lineEdit's value on the label

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, there are two ways to pass information (or actions) between instances of different classes:

You can make one of the two forms be aware of the other, i.e. give
`SecondForm` a method like this:

```
void setLabelTextAndShow(QString);
```

and call it from `FirstForm`. This implies some important things:
`FirstForm` has to know `SecondForm` public interface and must be
able to access it (i.e. must have a pointer, at least, to the
`SecondForm` instance).

Or you keep the forms agnostic about each other, using the Qt signal/slot builtin mechanism.

So, in SecondForm, instead of a public method like above, you have a `slot`:

```
private slots:
  void setLabelTextAndShow(QString);
```

while in FirstForm you declare a `signal`:

```
signals:
  void pushBttonClicked(QString lineEditText);
```

which will be 'emitted' when the pushButton is clicked:

```
void FirstForm::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
  emit pushBttonClicked(ui->lineEdit->text());
  this->close();
}
```

and caught in SecondForm slot:

```
void SecondForm::setLabelTextAndShow(QString text)
{
  ui->label->setText(text);
  this->show();
}
```

You must connect signal and slot before using them. Let it happen in main:

```
#include "firstform.h"
#include "secondform.h"

#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  QApplication app(argc, argv);

  FirstForm f1;
  SecondForm f2;

  QObject::connect(&f1, SIGNAL(pushBttonClicked(QString)), &f2, SLOT(setLabelTextAndShow(QString)));

  f1.show();

  return app.exec();
}
```

With this second method, you avoided creating a **dependence** between classes, which is pretty good in terms of **reusability**.

Comment: I have another question,

there are two Windows in this project. the first one is naming as firstform and the other as seconform.

I integer declared a variable naming x in the firstform.h

int x;

and I assigned a value to that variable in the firstform.cpp

x=10;

after that user run the program,
in the firstform the user click on the button. the secondform will be open, and in the secondform window on the label, the variable value should display. (10)

it means the data in the lineEdit in the first window should pass to the second window's label

Comment: I think you should make a proper question out of this. Not that I don't want to help you, but if you post questions where they're supposed to be (not in comments) you have more chances to have them answered. Also, I strongly suggest you to post some code along with your question, for the same reason: it will be more likely to be answered. Have a nice day.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47848139/pass-a-window-integer-variable-value-to-another-window-label

Comment: There are two windows in this project. Those are indicated as the FirstForm and the SecondForm. There’s a button in the first form and a label in the second form.
I declared an integer variable as int x; in the file called first form.h. I assigned a value to x in the file called firstform.cpp. The value is 10 (x=10).
When the user click the button on the first form and if the project is running, the second form must be opened and 10 must be displayed in the label.

Comment: So, it's basically the same question. Don't you think?

Comment: yea. :( im still trying. but can't fix it, can you comment the code for it please