# pass a window integer variable value to another window label

Tags: c++, qt

There are two windows in this project. Those are indicated as the `FirstForm` and the `SecondForm`. There’s a `button` in the first form and a `label` in the second form.

I declared an integer variable as `int x;` in the file called `first form.h`. I assigned a value to `x` in the file called `firstform.cpp`. The value is `10 (x=10)`.

When the user click the `button` on the first form and if the project is running, the second form must be opened and `10` must be displayed in the `label`.

firstform.h

```
private:
SecondForm *nextWindow;
int x;
```

firstform.cpp

```
void FirstForm::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    hide();
    nextWindow = new SecondForm(this);
    nextWindow->show();
    x=10;
}
```

Comment: Please copy code into a code block. Also, it is not clear what you are asking. If you have code that does not compile, please include the errors in a separate code block.

Comment: can you see the code now

Comment: You should make sure the names in the text matches the ones in the code. Do you really have a space in the file name?

Comment: Well, for starters your variable `x` is private in firstform so it cannot be accessed directly. Also, you first open the second form and **then** set `x`. So what do you expect the second form to display??